# Outsheet to quote and comma delimited text

Tags: delimiter, stata

My variables in Stata are of the form:

```
  First Name: Allen
  Last Name: Von Schmidt
  Birth Year: 1965
  County: Cape May
  State: New Jersey

  First Name: Lee Roy
  Last Name: McBride
  Birth Year: 1967
  County: Cook
  State: Illinois
```

I would like to `outsheet` them to create quote and comma separated rows in a .txt as:

```
 "Allen,"Von Schmidt","1965","Cape May","New Jersey"
 "Lee Roy","McBride","1967","Cook","Illinois"
```

How can I use `outsheet` (or another command) to do this?  Do I need to make the numerics into strings first?  Do I need to add a commas to each variable first?

I have tried the following:

```
outsheet first last birth_year county state using FileName.txt, nolabel delim(",")
```

This seems to work ok except that it does not put the numeric variables inside "".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand why you want this, but Stata's practice here as elsewhere is that only strings are placed in double quotes. So, to output numeric variables as if they were strings you do need to convert them first to string variables. The `tostring` command is designed for this.

But this is an awkward thing to do, and on the whole a bad idea.

First, and easier: if you use `tostring` you change your data, and numeric operations become impossible on the new string variables. That is relatively easy to work around. Just make sure you `save` your data first before using `tostring` and then read it back in again after exporting the data. Or use `preserve` followed by `restore`.

Second, and more problematic: you need to worry about loss of detail for any numeric variables that are not integer. `tostring` does have options that help here, but there are no guarantees of keeping every bit unless you get into nightmare territory of exporting hexadecimal. That's true of `outsheet` any way, but a warning should do no harm.

I am aware of the history of `tostring`, as its original author. I'll put on record that although it is a solution for what you appear to want to do, there are pitfalls as above and I don't recommend this way of working.

It would be better to explain why you think you need to do this. `outsheet`'s export of numerics and strings seems to have worked well for export to other software, not least spreadsheets, over many uses.

P.S. as emphasised elsewhere, Stata does not regard " " as separators. They are delimiters for strings, but not separators for fields (or words in Stata's sense).

Comment: In this application, the tostring might be ok.  There are only 2 such numeric variables in the data I have.  One if the position of the data.  That is, the row the data is located in.  The second is the birth year, which is the same for everybody in the .txt and for which I know.  I just want the format all of the variables to be the same in the .txt . . .

Comment: It's your call, but you have not explained why.

Comment: because the rest of the data are formatted that way so i want this to be consistent with it

Comment: I will let my advice stand.

Comment: oh, all of the numerics are integer.  so i guess the 2nd problem you list won't be a problem?

Comment: As I said, no guarantees. Very large integers could easily be messed up unless you take care of the format used in `tostring`.

Comment: Your years of birth should be fine, as this is not prehistoric history or science fiction. Another case where you might run into problems is if you have numeric variables that have value labels. I don't think that's the case with your data given what outsheet sheets out.